# Undefined identifier error with enum in the separate module

Tags: d

I am having troubles to use the enum defined in the separate module.
When I try to access it, I am getting "Undefined identifier" error:

```
// CodeEnum.d

enum CodeEnum
{
    OK = 200,
    FAIL = 400
}

unittest
{
    auto e = CodeEnum.OK; // Works!
}
```

-

```
// Reply.d

import CodeEnum;

unittest
{
    auto.e = CodeEnum.OK; // Error: undefined identifier 'OK'
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

*By the way, I've also posted this to the digitalmars-d-learn, but I don't see my email anywhere on the internet (list archive or forum) - is the list moderated in some way?*

Comment: The newsgroup isn't moderated but it might have just randomly dropped the message... the server has had a few periods of outage this week (I think the admins are moving it to a new location but i'm not really sure)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the module is called `CodeEnum`, `CodeEnum.OK` refers to a symbol `OK` in the module `CodeEnum`.

Use `CodeEnum.CodeEnum.OK`, or use a selective import: `import CodeEnum: CodeEnum;`, or give the module or the enum a different name.

Answer (score 2):

Your module name and enum name are in a conflict. Rename either the enum or the module name for your code to compile.

Comment: Ha! I would never guess this, but it really makes sense, thanks!